# Issue with Data files importing into include file with for loop in Jekyll

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

So I am working on a client website and working on trying to pull data from a data file I am working on. I have done this multiple times and for some reason this time it does not want to work properly.

So here is the data file and the structure that it is in right now:

```
- section: accordion
  tab:
    - info: Our Mission
      tab-index: headingOne
      pane: paneOne
      label: A
      content: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id harum, molestiae nemo. Delectus commodi magni ad ratione quisquam aliquid suscipit est, at molestias praesentium iste, vero.
```

Then here is the code that I am working on for the include to call it as such:

```
{% assign buttons = site.data.accordions %}
<ul class="list-inline">
{% for tab in buttons.tab %}
<li class="list-inline-item">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="collapse">
        {{ tab.info }}
    </a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Can someone explain to me what might have gone wrong this time with the code? I have been trying to wrap my brain around it for the past 4 hours and nothing is working for me.

Comment: "Frustrating issue" and "this time it does not want to work properly" are not the problem statements with which we can help you. Please, be more specific when describe your problem.

Comment: updated the title, that better? And also would you have any idea on what might be wrong with the code.

Comment: No, your problem statement is still unclear. Examples of clear problem statements: "When I run it, it prints error message '<...>', or "When I run it, it prints 'A' but I expect 'B'".

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your data file doesn't allow you to access `site.data.accordions.tab` as you have it in your `for` loop.

As as test you can call your assignments to see their output:

```
{% assign buttons = site.data.accordions %}
{{ buttons }}
```

You should see the output as:

```html
{"section"=>"accordion", "tab"=>[{"info"=>"Our Mission", "tab-index"=>"headingOne", "pane"=>"paneOne", "label"=>"A", "content"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id harum, molestiae nemo. Delectus commodi magni ad ratione quisquam aliquid suscipit est, at molestias praesentium iste, vero."}]}
```

In order to loop your `tab` data as you wish, you'll need to change your `for` loop to:

```
{% for tab in buttons[0].tab %}
```

Comment: Thanks for that help, it made me realize that I was calling it a different way than I used to with the loop I had used.